# Subscript in JSON

Tags: json, character-encoding

I have the following JSON assigned directly to a JS variable:

```
{
    "name": "NaHCO3",
    "parent": "Top Level",
    "_children": [
        {
          ...
        },
     ]
},
```

With the name attribute, I want it to be NaHCO<sub>3</sub>, **not** NaHCO3. How do I achieve this?
I tried looking for a HTML entity for this, but it seems that there isn't one.

Comment: You will either have to store it as HTML (using `<sub>`) or use a third party library to parse chemical names into proper display formats.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the char `&#8323;` or `\u2083`.

`\u2083` is what PHP uses to encode into a JSON:

```
$mol_encoded = json_encode(html_entity_decode('NaHCO&#8323;'));
$mol_decoded = json_decode($mol_encoded);

echo "$mol_encoded\n$mol_decoded";
```

returns:

```
"NaHCO\u2083"
NaHCO₃
```

and in JS `JSON.parse('"NaHCO\u2083"')` returns `"NaHCO₃"`

Comment: Not perfectly what I wanted but it seems okay. +1 anyways.

Comment: this is the way PHP encodes into JSON for instance, once you extract it it comes back to a readable string, see my edited answer.

Comment: this will work with the angular as well. I tried into the print data to view inside the angular, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not markup language. So it does not care what are the meaning of the values it carries. Somstimes you can  use UTF entities as there's tons of various symbols in UTF (like  [subscript three](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2083/index.htm) you look for):

```
{
    "name": "NaHCO&#8323;",
    ...
},
```

But if you want certain markup features in general , you must choose the way to achieve it, and then format the value stored to use it. I.e. you can use HTML tags or markdown etc.